# Automating JX installation process via ansible2.9

Tags: ansible-2.x, jenkins-x

Am trying to install jenkins-x version 2.0.785 via ansible 2.9.9.

How do I handle the prompts like **"Please enter the name you wish to use with git:"** that I get while installing JX? There are multiple prompts to be handled that I will get when I execute the JX install command.

I get the above mentioned prompt even though "--git-username=automation" is already passed in the JX install command. **I tried with both expect and shell module in ansible.**

Kindly, suggest me a solution where I can handle these prompts via ansible.

**Tried:-**

```
- name: Handling multiple prompts
  expect:
    command: jx install --git-provider-kind bitbucketserver --git-provider-url http://rtx-swtl-git.fnc.net.local --git-username automation --default-environment-prefix TestProject --git-api-token MzI1ODg1NjA1NTk4OqjiP9N3lr4iHt9L5rofdaWMqsgW --on-premise --external-ip {{ hostvars[groups["kubemaster"][0]]["ip"] }} --verbose --static-jenkins=true --provider=openshift
    responses:
      Question:
        - Please enter the name you wish to use with git: automation
    timeout: 60
```

```
- name: Handling multiple prompts
  expect:
    command: jx install --git-provider-kind bitbucketserver --git-provider-url http://rtx-swtl-git.fnc.net.local --git-username automation --default-environment-prefix TestProject --git-api-token MzI1ODg1NjA1NTk4OqjiP9N3lr4iHt9L5rofdaWMqsgW --on-premise --external-ip {{ hostvars[groups["kubemaster"][0]]["ip"] }} --verbose --static-jenkins=true --provider=openshift
    responses:
      Please enter the name you wish to use with git: "automation"
```

```
- name: Handling multiple prompts
  become: yes
  shell: |
    automation '' | jx install --git-provider-kind bitbucketserver --git-provider-url http://rtx-swtl-git.fnc.net.local --git-username automation --default-environment-prefix Testproject --git-api-token MzI1ODg1NjA1NTk4OqjiP9N3lr4iHt9L5rofdaWMqsgW --on-premise --external-ip {{ hostvars[groups["kubemaster"][0]]["ip"] }} --verbose --static-jenkins true --provider openshift
```

These doesn't give any errors in stderr section of ansible logs, the only thing is I receive the below attached logs in RED and it doesn't proceed further with the installation steps.

**Output:-**

```
fatal: [master]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "jx install --git-provider-kind bitbucketserver --git-provider-url http://rtx-swtl-git.fnc.net.local --git-username automation --default-environment-prefix TestProject --git-api-token MzI1ODg1NjA1NTk4OqjiP9N3lr4iHt9L5rofdaWMqsgW --on-premise --external-ip 167.254.204.90 --verbose --static-jenkins=true --provider=openshift --domain=jenkinsx.io",
    "delta": "0:03:00.190343",
    "end": "2020-06-17 06:44:03.620694",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "chdir": null,
            "command": "jx install --git-provider-kind bitbucketserver --git-provider-url http://rtx-swtl-git.fnc.net.local --git-username automation --default-environment-prefix TestProject --git-api-token MzI1ODg1NjA1NTk4OqjiP9N3lr4iHt9L5rofdaWMqsgW --on-premise --external-ip 167.254.204.90 --verbose --static-jenkins=true --provider=openshift --domain=jenkinsx.io",
            "creates": null,
            "echo": false,
            "removes": null,
            "responses": {
                "Question": [
                    {
                        "Please enter the name you wish to use with git": "automation"
                    },
                    {
                        "Please enter the email address you wish to use with git": "automation@fujitsu.com"
                    },
                    {
                        "\\? Do you wish to use automation as the local Git user for http://rtx-swtl-git.fnc.net.local server": "y"
                    },
                    {
                        "\\? Do you wish to use http://rtx-swtl-git.fnc.net.local as the pipelines Git server": "y"
                    }
                ]
            },
            "timeout": 180
        }
    },
    "msg": "command exceeded timeout",
    "rc": null,
    "start": "2020-06-17 06:41:03.430351",
    "stdout": "\u001b[1m\u001b[32m?\u001b[0m\u001b[0m \u001b[1mConfigured Jenkins installation type\u001b[0m: \u001b[36mStatic Jenkins Server and Jenkinsfiles\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: checking installation flags\r\n\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: flags after checking - &{ConfigFile: InstallOnly:false Domain: ExposeControllerURLTemplate: ExposeControllerPathMode: AzureRegistrySubscription: DockerRegistry:docker-registry.default.svc:5000 DockerRegistryOrg: Provider:openshift VersionsRepository:https://github.com/jenkins-x/jenkins-x-versions.git VersionsGitRef: Version: LocalHelmRepoName:releases Namespace:jx CloudEnvRepository:https://github.com/jenkins-x/cloud-environments NoDefaultEnvironments:false RemoteEnvironments:false DefaultEnvironmentPrefix:TestProject LocalCloudEnvironment:false EnvironmentGitOwner: Timeout:6000 HelmTLS:false RegisterLocalHelmRepo:false CleanupTempFiles:true Prow:false DisableSetKubeContext:false Dir: Vault:false RecreateVaultBucket:true Tekton:false KnativeBuild:false BuildPackName: Kaniko:false GitOpsMode:false NoGitOpsEnvApply:false NoGitOpsEnvRepo:false NoGitOpsEnvSetup:false NoGitOpsVault:false NextGeneration:false StaticJenkins:true LongTermStorage:false LongTermStorageBucketName: CloudBeesDomain: CloudBeesAuth:}\r\n\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: Setting the dev namespace to: \u001b[32mjx\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: Using helmBinary \u001b[32mhelm\u001b[0m with feature flag: \u001b[32mnone\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: \u001b[32mhelm\u001b[0m is already available on your PATH at \u001b[32m/usr/bin/helm\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: \u001b[32mkubectl\u001b[0m is already available on your PATH at \u001b[32m/usr/bin/kubectl\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: \u001b[32mhelm\u001b[0m is already available on your PATH at \u001b[32m/usr/bin/helm\u001b[0m\r\nContext \"jx/master-167-254-204-90-nip-io:8443/waruser\" modified.\r\n\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: \u001b[32mkubectl\u001b[0m is already available on your PATH at \u001b[32m/usr/bin/kubectl\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: \u001b[32mhelm\u001b[0m is already available on your PATH at \u001b[32m/usr/bin/helm\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: Storing the kubernetes provider openshift in the TeamSettings\r\n\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: Enabling helm template mode in the TeamSettings\r\nGit configured for user: \u001b[32mautomation\u001b[0m and email \u001b[32mautomation@fujitsu.com\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: Using \u001b[32mhelm2\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: Skipping \u001b[32mtiller\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: Using helmBinary \u001b[32mhelm\u001b[0m with feature flag: \u001b[32mtemplate-mode\u001b[0m\r\n\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: Initialising Helm '\u001b[32minit --client-only\u001b[0m'\r\nhelm installed and configured\r\nNot installing ingress as using OpenShift which uses Route and its own mechanism of ingress\r\nEnabling anyuid for the Jenkins service account in namespace jx\r\nscc \"anyuid\" added to: [\"system:serviceaccount:jx:jenkins\"]\r\nscc \"hostaccess\" added to: [\"system:serviceaccount:jx:jenkins\"]\r\nscc \"privileged\" added to: [\"system:serviceaccount:jx:jenkins\"]\r\nscc \"anyuid\" added to: [\"system:serviceaccount:jx:default\"]\r\n\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: Long Term Storage not supported by provider 'openshift', disabling this option\r\nSet up a Git username and API token to be able to perform CI/CD\r\n\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: merging pipeline secrets with local secrets\r\n\u001b[0G\u001b[2K\u001b[1;92m? \u001b[0m\u001b[1;99mDo you wish to use automation as the local Git user for http://rtx-swtl-git.fnc.net.local server: \u001b[0m\u001b[37m(Y/n) \u001b[0m\u001b[?25l\u001b7\u001b[999;999f\u001b[6n",
    "stdout_lines": [
        "\u001b[1m\u001b[32m?\u001b[0m\u001b[0m \u001b[1mConfigured Jenkins installation type\u001b[0m: \u001b[36mStatic Jenkins Server and Jenkinsfiles\u001b[0m",
        "\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: checking installation flags",
        "\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: flags after checking - &{ConfigFile: InstallOnly:false Domain: ExposeControllerURLTemplate: ExposeControllerPathMode: AzureRegistrySubscription: DockerRegistry:docker-registry.default.svc:5000 DockerRegistryOrg: Provider:openshift VersionsRepository:https://github.com/jenkins-x/jenkins-x-versions.git VersionsGitRef: Version: LocalHelmRepoName:releases Namespace:jx CloudEnvRepository:https://github.com/jenkins-x/cloud-environments NoDefaultEnvironments:false RemoteEnvironments:false DefaultEnvironmentPrefix:TestProject LocalCloudEnvironment:false EnvironmentGitOwner: Timeout:6000 HelmTLS:false RegisterLocalHelmRepo:false CleanupTempFiles:true Prow:false DisableSetKubeContext:false Dir: Vault:false RecreateVaultBucket:true Tekton:false KnativeBuild:false BuildPackName: Kaniko:false GitOpsMode:false NoGitOpsEnvApply:false NoGitOpsEnvRepo:false NoGitOpsEnvSetup:false NoGitOpsVault:false NextGeneration:false StaticJenkins:true LongTermStorage:false LongTermStorageBucketName: CloudBeesDomain: CloudBeesAuth:}",
        "\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: Setting the dev namespace to: \u001b[32mjx\u001b[0m",
        "\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: Using helmBinary \u001b[32mhelm\u001b[0m with feature flag: \u001b[32mnone\u001b[0m",
        "\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: \u001b[32mhelm\u001b[0m is already available on your PATH at \u001b[32m/usr/bin/helm\u001b[0m",
        "\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: \u001b[32mkubectl\u001b[0m is already available on your PATH at \u001b[32m/usr/bin/kubectl\u001b[0m",
        "\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: \u001b[32mhelm\u001b[0m is already available on your PATH at \u001b[32m/usr/bin/helm\u001b[0m",
        "Context \"jx/master-167-254-204-90-nip-io:8443/waruser\" modified.",
        "\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: \u001b[32mkubectl\u001b[0m is already available on your PATH at \u001b[32m/usr/bin/kubectl\u001b[0m",
        "\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: \u001b[32mhelm\u001b[0m is already available on your PATH at \u001b[32m/usr/bin/helm\u001b[0m",
        "\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: Storing the kubernetes provider openshift in the TeamSettings",
        "\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: Enabling helm template mode in the TeamSettings",
        "Git configured for user: \u001b[32mautomation\u001b[0m and email \u001b[32mautomation@fujitsu.com\u001b[0m",
        "\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: Using \u001b[32mhelm2\u001b[0m",
        "\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: Skipping \u001b[32mtiller\u001b[0m",
        "\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: Using helmBinary \u001b[32mhelm\u001b[0m with feature flag: \u001b[32mtemplate-mode\u001b[0m",
        "\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: Initialising Helm '\u001b[32minit --client-only\u001b[0m'",
        "helm installed and configured",
        "Not installing ingress as using OpenShift which uses Route and its own mechanism of ingress",
        "Enabling anyuid for the Jenkins service account in namespace jx",
        "scc \"anyuid\" added to: [\"system:serviceaccount:jx:jenkins\"]",
        "scc \"hostaccess\" added to: [\"system:serviceaccount:jx:jenkins\"]",
        "scc \"privileged\" added to: [\"system:serviceaccount:jx:jenkins\"]",
        "scc \"anyuid\" added to: [\"system:serviceaccount:jx:default\"]",
        "\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: Long Term Storage not supported by provider 'openshift', disabling this option",
        "Set up a Git username and API token to be able to perform CI/CD",
        "\u001b[36mDEBUG\u001b[0m: merging pipeline secrets with local secrets",
        "\u001b[0G\u001b[2K\u001b[1;92m? \u001b[0m\u001b[1;99mDo you wish to use automation as the local Git user for http://rtx-swtl-git.fnc.net.local server: \u001b[0m\u001b[37m(Y/n) \u001b[0m\u001b[?25l\u001b7\u001b[999;999f\u001b[6n"
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
master                     : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

**Helm, JX, Git, Ansible versions:-**
[image]